# SQL SUM function with other column values

Tags: sql, aggregate

Am new to SQL. i need the desired output.

Input

| EMPNAME | SALARY |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 1000 |
| BBB | 2000 |

Output

| EMPNAME | SALARY | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1000 | 3000 |
| BBB | 2000 | 3000 |

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: See the example (near "By contrast, window operations do not collapse groups of query rows to a single output row. Instead, they produce a result for each row. Like the preceding queries, the following query uses SUM(), but this time as a window function:")  in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions.  In this case, you want a partitioned sum with no partition or order by.  This takes the sum over all the rows:

```
select t.*, sum(salary) over () as total_salary
from t;
```

Note that an `order by` in the window function is for a *cumulative* sum.  You simply want the total so `order by` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
drop table if exists #batch;
go
create table #batch(
  empname    varchar(10) not null,
  salary     int not NULL);

insert into #batch(empname, salary) values
('aaa', 1000),
('bbb', 2000);

select *, sum(salary) over (order by (select null)) from #batch;
```

```
empname salary  TOTAL
aaa     1000    3000
bbb     2000    3000
```

[EDIT] Please note, in this query the ORDER BY value is an optional placeholder (ordering by a constant or null does not affect the results).  It could be left blank (which looks odd imo), or I've seen some SO answers use `order by (select @@spid)` (which also looks odd imo)

Comment: this works exactly how i wanted.. Thank you so much SteveC

Comment: @HelpSeeker please mark as answer if it was helpful :)